# TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The global scope is shutting down

Tags: typescript, dynamics-crm, fetch-api, dynamics-365

I am **occasionally** getting the error from the title on load of my Dynamics 365 form while executing a fetch request to Dynamics 365 API. The thing I am doing is trying to send a context object to embedded html web resource and initiate a script method referenced from the html resource. My code is following:

1. On the form on-load event I initialize the context object in html resource like this:

```js
export function setContextForFileUploader(executionContext) {
    const formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    const wrControl = formContext.getControl('WebResource_myWebResource');
    if (wrControl) {
      wrControl.getContentWindow().then(function (contentWindow) {
        const contentAvailable = self.setInterval(async function () {
          if (contentWindow.setClientApiContext && contentWindow.myNS.EmailAttachmentUploader) {
            clearInterval(contentAvailable);
            contentWindow.setClientApiContext(Xrm, formContext);
            await contentWindow.myNS.EmailAttachmentUploader.DocumentLoaded();
          }
        }, 200);
      });
    }
  }
```

2. setClientApiContext is a function written directly between script tags in html web resource:

```js
function setClientApiContext(xrm, formContext) {
    window.myXrm = xrm;
    window.myFormContext = formContext;
    }
```

It is setting the value of 2 global variables.

3. myNS.EmailAttachmentUploader.DocumentLoaded is a function from a script referenced by html web resource. It is awaiting another function which returns a promise returned by **fetch**. The code is like following:

```js
    export async function DocumentLoaded() {
        
        const response = await PopulateEntityInfo();
        if ((window as any).entityCollectionName == '' || (window as any).entityCollectionName == undefined) {
          showAlertDialog(
            "Something went wrong...",
            300,
            600
          );
          return;
        }
      }
      
      function PopulateEntityInfo() {
        const query =
          'EntityDefinitions?$select=EntitySetName,LogicalName&$filter=ObjectTypeCode eq ' + (window as any).entityTypecode;
        
        return fetch(encodeURI('API_URL' + webApiQuery))
          .then(async (response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
              const data = await response.json();
              if (data != null) {
                (window as any).entityCollectionName = data.value[0].EntitySetName;
                (window as any).logicalName = data.value[0].LogicalName;
        }
            } else
              showAlertDialog(
                'There was a problem fetching entity definitions.',
                300,
                600
              );
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            showAlertDialog(error, 300, 600);
          });
      }
```

The **fetch** is occasionally failing with error message from the title. I was not able to google out anything for this error and I am not sure how is global scope shutting down. I hope someone here can point out what am I doing wrong here and what could be causing this error. The worse part of course is that it is happening occasionally.

Comment: I am not sure what is happening here. First you could replace `.then(async (response) => {` by `.then(response => {`. The `async` there could mess things up. Your code attempts to call a script on the window loaded in the IFrame. This is a brittle approach. When the user is navigating the window may be unloaded. At least the error message suggests the window object the `fetch` function is created on is being disposed at he same moment the fetch function is called. This is possible because the fetch is executed on the UI thread of the parent form window.

Comment: Thanks for response @Henk van Boeijen . I cannot do the replacement you suggest since I have an await in that function. It makes sense that window object is being disposed, but how and why this is happening? If I have a form which hosts an IFrame to html file and that file references some scripts that call fetch, how many window objects will I be dealing with? And which one would fetch use?

Comment: I think an `await` should not be applied inside a promise handler. Instead you should just return the async function call. You then add a next `then()` handler where you process the result of the call. That is how promises work.

Comment: Accessing window objects is complex. A good option would be to apply messaging. (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event). When you are on Dynamics 365 Online, I can recommend developing a custom PCF control instead; it could simplify the integration of your custom component considerably.